# Adding breadcrumbs in vue application

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am currently working in Vue.js framework and I need to set breadcrumbs for application. I'm using store component, right now I can get the current value and back state, but I need to get the path between pages in breadcrumbs. So I though of using stack [] for storing the index.

I am stuck in this, can anyone help me out?

```html
const _state = {
  current: '',
  back: false,
  stack: [],
};


const getters = {
  breadcrumb: s => s,
};

const actions = {
  SET_BACK({ commit }, value) {
    commit('SET_BACK', value);
  },
  SET_CURRENT({ commit }, value) {
    commit('SET_CURRENT', value);
  },
  SET_STACK ()
};

const mutations = {
  SET_CURRENT(state, value) {
    state.current = value;
  },
  SET_BACK(state, value) {
    state.back = value;
  },
};

export default {
  state: _state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

I need to fix the stack method

Basic idea is to get the pages path in breadcrumbs, eg:

**home > page1> section1>**

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing in a custom way, you will have to deal with a lot of problems like knowing when to clean your stack, the real URL of each component (duplicate the Route work) and so on... For instance, how will you tell the `path` of each component to your `stack` function?

If you are using Vue Router, you could use the trick of using the additional information in the Router file to set the Breadcrumb of each section, like:

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld,
      meta: {
        breadcrumb: [
          { name: 'Hello World' }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/area1',
      name: 'Area1',
      component: Area1,
      meta: {
        breadcrumb: [
          { name: 'Area 1' }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/area12',
      name: 'Area12',
      component: Area12,
      meta: {
        breadcrumb: [
          { name: 'Area 1', link: 'area11' },
          { name: 'Area 2' }
        ]
      }
}
...
```

Here you have a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@fagnersaraujo/automated-breadcrumbs-with-vuejs-7e1051de8028) and the code source: https://github.com/iFgR/vue-breadcrumbs.

I recommend using either the Router or a Breadcrumb component like https://github.com/samturrell/vue-breadcrumbs or https://github.com/Scrum/vue-2-breadcrumbs.

To end, I just found this "Very simple Vue breadcrumbs in 40 lines of code" [here](https://github.com/NxtChg/pieces/tree/master/js/vue/vs-crumbs); maybe it adapts better to you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i need to set mutations for stack method ( to get the page navigation in breadcrumbs)

Comment: check to next comment answer

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template>
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li v-if="back" class="back">
        <font-awesome-icon class="back-icon" @click="goBack" :icon="backIcon" />Back
      </li>

        <li class="current">
        <font-awesome-icon class="forward-icon" :icon="forwardIcon" />{{current}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: the current and back state is working indvidually  in breadcrumb, now i want to get the path in breadcrumb,

Comment: i am adding stack function, i am not sure of the logic to get index value in mutations

Answer (score 0):

I was happily using the [`vue-2-crumbs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-2-crumbs) plugin however then discovered that it didn't work with SSR so created my own component.

**Crumbs.vue**

```
<template>
    <ul v-if="stack.length > 0" class="crumbs">
        <li v-for="item in stack" class="crumbs__item" :class="item.class">
            <router-link :to="{ name: item.name }" class="crumbs__link">
                {{ item.label }}
            </router-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:    'Crumbs',
        data() {
            return { stack: [] }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.buildStack()
        },
        methods: {
            buildStack() {
                this.stack = []
                this.addPage(this.$router.currentRoute)
                this.stack = this.stack.reverse()
            },
            addPage(route, first) {
                this.stack.push({
                    name:  route.name,
                    label: route.meta?.breadcrumb?.label || route.name.replace('.', ' '),
                    class: 'crumbs__item--' + (typeof first === 'undefined' ? 'current' : 'parent')
                })
                if (route.meta.breadcrumb.parent) {
                    const parent = this.getRoute(route.meta.breadcrumb.parent)
                    this.addPage(parent, true)
                }
            },
            getRoute(name) {
                return this.$router.options.routes.find(route => route.name === name)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And a little css to go with it:

```
.crumbs {
    display:         flex;
    flex-direction:  row;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:          1rem 0 2rem 0;
    padding:         0;
    flex-wrap:       wrap;
}

.crumbs__link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.crumbs__item--parent::after {
    content: '>';
}
```

My routes are setup in the same was as required for the vue-2-crumbs plugin.

I'm surprised that my component is 42 lines and yet the vue-2-crumbs plugin is 2317 lines. Maybe there is some extra functionality in there, but even so!

For my use it performs in exactly the same way.